# IE9 selectSingleNode missing from beta, how to overcome this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmldocument, internet-explorer-9, xpath

XMLDocument object in Internet Explorer 9 does not contain definition for selectSingleNode Xpath-based traversal anymore.

Of course, I googled a little and came across this thread, where it is unsure is it missing by specification or by the fact it is still "in beta".

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/0dc55c4d-4a63-4a12-b5cc-e4e12cc13d91

Anyone have idea how to resolve this, is there some other way of XPath traversal trough XMLDocument that is "IE9 Way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath is not available in IE9's native XML support; we recommend moving to the Selectors API instead. If required, XPath support is still available using the MSXML ActiveX objects.

Comment: So it's for sure gone and not coming back, not something temporary?

Comment: Anything's possible, but no plans to bring it back have been announced. You can send feedback on IE9 here: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE.  Thanks!